# pandas read csv normalizing dates with python3

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Relativity new python/pandas user here. I need some help figuring out how to normalize dates. I have a data set where the dates column comes in different types of formats. Something like this(so far those 2 are the types of formats I've seen):

```
 DATE          PRICE
 12/26/2015     XXX
 12/26/2015     YYY
 25-Dec-15      ZZZ
 25-Dec-15      WWW
```

Whenever I print it out, all it says is `dtype:object`. What additional steps do to normalize the dates?

*Edit: just to add that this is assuming that the file is a csv file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming its a csv file

```
df=pd.read_csv("f.csv")
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
print df.dtypes
```

This should convert 'DATE' into datetime object

Comment: yes, this assumes that the file I'm trying to read is a csv file. Thanks, this actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better is parse datetime in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) by parameter `parse_dates`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""DATE          PRICE
 12/26/2015     XXX
 12/26/2015     YYY
 25-Dec-15      ZZZ
 25-Dec-15      WWW"""

#after testing change io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", parse_dates=['DATE'])

print df

        DATE PRICE
0 2015-12-26   XXX
1 2015-12-26   YYY
2 2015-12-25   ZZZ
3 2015-12-25   WWW

print df.dtypes

DATE     datetime64[ns]
PRICE            object
dtype: object

print df.index

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Or if you want set `index` to `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#after testing change io.StringIO(temp) to filename    
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", parse_dates=['DATE'], index_col=['DATE'] )

print df

           PRICE
DATE            
2015-12-26   XXX
2015-12-26   YYY
2015-12-25   ZZZ
2015-12-25   WWW

print df.dtypes

PRICE    object
dtype: object
print df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-26', '2015-12-26', '2015-12-25', '2015-12-25'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'DATE', freq=None)
```